# Regex which should contain phrase and a matching group in any order

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to check a string for the phrase "Alla dagar" either presided or followed by `digit(possible space?)-(possible space?)digit` and it may or may not contain a line break in between.

Examples:

```
### Item 1 - Should match
8-17
Alla dagar

### Item 2 - Should match
Alla dagar
08-21

### Item 3 - Should not match
8-17

### Item 4 - Should match
7 - 9 Alla dagar

### Item 5 - Should match
Alla dagar 17-23
```

I came up with two regex which neither I get to work. The first is [this one](https://regex101.com/r/LK9MAH/2):

```
^(?=.*s|Alla dagar)(?=(?<from>\d+) ?- ?(?<to>\d+)).*$
```

[The other regex I wrote](https://regex101.com/r/w7IuHk/1) didn't work either, because it's not exclusive. It matches also if "alla dagar" doesn't exist because these are optional.

```
^((?:s|Alla dagar))?\n*?((?<from>\d+) ?- ?(?<to>\d+))\n*?((?:s|Alla dagar))?\n?$
```

My question, how can I make a match using `((?<from>\d+) ?- ?(?<to>\d+))` and require the phrase `Alla dagar` to exist in the string?

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/biEl5O/1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. Exactly like that. Thanks! I'm using PCRE2 to be used inside Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?<from>\d+)\s*-\s*(?<to>\d+)\s*Alla dagar|Alla dagar\s*(?<from>\d+)\s*-\s*(?<to>\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/biEl5O/1). Make sure you use the `PCRE_INFO_JCHANGED` flag (`(?J)` at the start of the regex can be used in case you want to incorporate it into the regex itself) to enable multiple named capturing groups inside a single expression.

*Details*:

- `(?<from>\d+)` - Group "from": one or more digits
- `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(?<to>\d+)` - Group "to": one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `Alla dagar` - a fixed string
- `|` - or
- `Alla dagar\s*(?<from>\d+)\s*-\s*(?<to>\d+)` - a fixed string, zero or more whitespaces, Group "from": one or more digits, a hyphen enclosed with zero or more whitespaces, Group "to": one or more digits.